# Find and Remove duplicates from list while concatenating second list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists, the first list contains duplicate values.
What I need is to remove the duplicates from `List1` and also merge the values in `List2` on the same indices as `List1` duplicate values.

What I Have:

```
List1 = ['show1', 'show2', 'show3', 'show2', 'show4', 'show4']
List2 = ['1pm', '10am', '11pm', '2pm', '5pm', '3pm']
```

What I Need:

```
List1 = ['show1', 'show2', 'show3', 'show4']
List2 = ['1pm', '10am | 2pm', '11pm', '5pm | 3pm']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using Python 3.7+, You can try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

List1 = ['show1', 'show2', 'show3', 'show2', 'show4', 'show4']
List2 = ['1pm', '10am', '11pm', '2pm', '5pm', '3pm']

d = defaultdict(list)

for show, time in zip(List1, List2):
    d[show].append(time)

List1 = list(d.keys())
List2 = [' | '.join(times) for times in d.values()]
print(List1)
print(List2)
```

Output:

```
['show1', 'show2', 'show3', 'show4']
['1pm', '10am | 2pm', '11pm', '5pm | 3pm']
```

For version less than 3.7, you can replace the last few lines with this (slightly more work):

```
List1 = []
List2 = []

for show, times in d.items():
    List1.append(show)
    List2.append(' | '.join(times))
```

Comment: You should note that the order of `List1` is not guaranteed in many versions of Python (before 3.6, 3.6 for anything not CPython).

Comment: Adding to what @RoryDaulton said regarding `defaultdict.keys()` not preserving sort order for pre-3.6 Python versions, that problem is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770251/defaultdict-on-append-elements-maintain-keys-sorted-in-the-order-of-addition

Comment: @RoryDaulton - for clarity, I assume you are referring to the order of `List1` after it is mutated into a list of the `defaultdict` keys (not the order of the first initialized list).

Comment: @benvc Correct, this answer wont preserve the original order of the items in `List1` because `defaultdict.keys()` doesn't guarantee order in pre-3.6 Python versions (as @RoryDaulton pointed out).

Comment: @RoryDaulton I added a more version-friendly solution.